# How to Parse the Results of CMDlet into Array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am sure there is an easy answer to this question, but I cannot find it anywhere. I would like to know how to parse the results of `Get-Mailbox | select Alias` into an array so each time I use the array it does not show the items as "@{Alias=username}".

I have tired this, but it seems to make the values not text:

```
$arrayname = Get-Mailbox | select Alias
```

I am sure this question has been asked before, but I cannot find it.

Essentially I would like to get the Alias' from the `Get-Mailbox` command into an array so that I can use the `foreach` cmdlet to get specific folder information from a user like so:

```
>> $aliases = Get-Mailbox | select Alias
>> Foreach ($username in $aliases) {Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -identity $username | select FolderPath | where {$_.FolderPath -like '*Deleted*'} | Export-CSV "C:\users\username\desktop\allusers-deletedfolder-postarchive.csv" -NoTypeInformation}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cmdlet already produces an array, only that its elements are mailbox objects, not strings. Selecting the `Alias` property restricts the object properties, but still leaves you with an array of objects (hence the output you observed). You need to expand the property:

```
$arrayname = Get-Mailbox | select -Expand Alias
```

or echo it in a loop:

```
$arrayname = Get-Mailbox | % { $_.Alias }
```

Comment: Third alternative: Could just reference Alias each time - `$aliases | %{ Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -identity $_.Alias | ...`. Slightly more convoluted, though.